# Select rows that fully match the end of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

`Column1` has a record with the value `example`.

A user submits the value `somethingwithexample`.

The end of his string matches the value in `Column1`. How to SELECT `Column1` in MySQL?

Comment: is it only @ the end of the record

Comment: not getting you correctly .. can you elaborate ?? you need only `example` word or everyword that includes `example`

Comment: so you can create a stored procedure where you can accept the `word` which you want to compare and then pass it to the `identifier` .

Comment: i have tried to answer this check if it works

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `like` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  :userinput LIKE CONCAT('%', mycolumn)
```

EDIT:
As noted in the comment, if the column is empty, this will evaluate as `userinput LIKE '%'`, which is by definition always `true`. This edge-case should be handled explicitly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  mycolumn IS NOT NULL AND
       mycolumn != '' AND
       :userinput LIKE CONCAT('%', mycolumn)
```

Comment: Looking good, but it's also selecting rows with empty values. Any further recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where $userInput like concat('%', col)
```

Comment: It's working but it's also selecting empty rows and integers, any more idea?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't quite get it.

Comment: So if the user input is `stackoverflow`, it's selecting all rows with the word `flow`, so this is working. But its also selecting rows with the value `1` and `NULL`.

Comment: Still don't get it. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/589338/2. Expand it to the problem and post the new link.

Comment: whoops, sorry. Not selecting `null` but empty strings. If the input contains numbers then it selects it e.g. `stack1overflow` selects `1`

Comment: Sure, if you have a column with content `1`.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought it matched from the end of the substring, which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name
where column_name like '%example'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tablename where value like '%example';
```

will select all rows whose value column has values that are ending with example
for example: mathexample, scienceexample;

```
select * from tablename where value like '%example%';
```

will select all rows whose value column has values such as mathexample1, scienceexample2 etc